# Symfony Console Section Not Clearing All Lines

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-console

I'm trying to create a console table that refreshes itself every few seconds (this is to refresh stock data).

However I find that after a certain length, $section->clear() just doesn't clear all the lines. In my terminal it seems not to clear anything above 23 lines. I'm on a Mac using Catalina, not sure if that matters.

My code is like this:

```
$section = $output->section();

while (true) {
    $quote = $tradier->getQuote($symbol, true);
    $this->renderQuoteTable($quote, $section);
    sleep($input->getOption('interval'));
    $section->clear();
}
```

The actual renderQuoteTable() method just creates a table, passing $section to it, fetches the quote data and renders it.

With a table 23 lines or less, it clears all the lines.

But my table is 27 lines long, and so every time it refreshes, the top 4 lines remain.

Not sure if this is a bug, an issue with terminal on the Mac, or just wrong coding.

Comment: I believe it's somewhat of a bug, because I encountered it too. I believe input reads shift the lines (because user ends them with a line break) and that at the very least isn't covered by the section clear command.

Comment: Thanks @Jakumi. I'm wondering whether it's a terminal issue, I tried manually printing out the control characters to move the cursor and the top four lines still stubbornly remain. No idea why.